# Как и где просмотреть код реализации оператора switch в java?

Tags: java

да и вообще реализацию других стандартных операторов и классов java? 
просто даже не знаю, что ввести в поисковике, чтобы найти это всё)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наташенька, операторы switch/if/goto называются операторами передачи управления и все реализуются на уровне машинных кодов, но не на уровне языка высокого уровня. Для Java машинными кодами являются т.н. байткоды виртуальной Java машины (JVM). Компилятор обычно сам решает в какую конкретно байткод инструкцию перевести тот или иной оператор управления. А инструкций передачи управления [много с десяток](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). В случае со `switch` скорее всего это будет инструкция `ifeq` для `case` и что-то другое для `default`

Далее по классам: классы Java API уже реализованы на самом Java с некоторыми включениями сишного кода (там где идет обращение к самой оси) - исходники есть в дистрибутиве SDK, скачивайте и изучайте.

Comment: Спасибо за полезный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если прям очень хочется все знать, можно посмотреть вот тут: [спецификация виртуальной машины языка Ява](http://www.uni-vologda.ac.ru/java/jvm/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

А просто загуглить [switch java](http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=switch+java&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)? И сходу же первая ссылка [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)!

Или это не такая информация как нужно?

Comment: это ни такая информация. мне сам кол switcha нужен, как его программисты написали при создании.

Comment: не как, это просто слово, которое дает указания компилятору